# URL dañada en Facebook developers, Inicio de sesión con Firebase

Tags: firebase, facebook, autenticación

estoy implementando inicio de sesión con facebook en mi aplicativo con firebase, he seguido todos los pasos que se encuentran en la documentación pero cuando la quiero pasar a modo publicado recibo este anuncio, en estado de prueba el inicio de sesión es exitoso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]